# Tick-size for dydx trading bot

Tags: python, bots, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to build a dydx trading bot and i'm having a problem with adjusting the right format for the buy_price function to be passed. Here's a snippet of for the buy order and sell order being passed:

```
        # Calculate the number of coins to buy
        buy_price = calculate_buy_price(dollar_amount)
        quantity = risk_amount / buy_price

        # Quantize the quantity to the nearest multiple of the quantum size
        quantum_size = Decimal('0.000000001')
        quantity = (Decimal(quantity) / quantum_size).quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN) * quantum_size

        # Calculate the rounded buy price
        tick_size = Decimal('0.000000001')  # Adjust the tick size as needed
        buy_price = (Decimal(buy_price) / tick_size).quantize(Decimal('1'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN) * tick_size

        # Calculate the rounded buy price that is divisible by the tick size
        rounded_buy_price = (buy_price // tick_size) * tick_size

        # Convert the buy price to string
        buy_price_str = str(rounded_buy_price)

        # Buy BTC with the specified position size
        print('Buy signal detected!')
        print('Buying {} BTC at price {}'.format(quantity, buy_price))
        buy_order = private_client.private.create_order(
            market='BTC-USD',
            side=ORDER_SIDE_BUY,
            position_id=1,
            limit_fee='0.015',
            order_type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
            price=buy_price_str,
            size=str(quantity),
            post_only=True,
            expiration_epoch_seconds=int(time.time()) + 600  # Set expiration time to 10 minutes from now
        )
        print('Buy order placed. Order ID: {}'.format(buy_order['id']))

        # Wait for the order to be filled
        time.sleep(request_interval)

        # Check if the current price is above the sell threshold
        response = requests.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            current_price = response.json()['bitcoin']['usd']
            if float(current_price) > sell_threshold:
                # Sell the entire BTC position
                print('Sell signal detected!')
                print('Selling all BTC at price {}'.format(current_price))
                sell_order = private_client.private.create_order(
                    market='BTC-USD',
                    side=ORDER_SIDE_SELL,
                    position_id=1,
                    limit_fee='0.015',
                    order_type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT,
                    price=str(current_price),
                    size='all'
                )
                print('Sell order placed. Order ID: {}'.format(sell_order['id']))
```

It also the gives me the following error:

```
Buy signal detected!
Buying 616.080000000 BTC at price 0.000162316
An error occurred in Main Trading Loop: DydxApiError(status_code=400, response={'errors': [{'msg': 'order with price: 0.000162316 must be divisble by tickSize: 1'}]})
```

Comment: You have defined `tick_size = Decimal('0.000000001')` but according to the error, tick size should be 1.